# Conditional likelihood of continuously-combounded returns

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

The simplest possible asset pricing model ist the geometric brownian motion for asset price. Here the price $S_t$ solve the familar

$$dS_t = (\mu +0.5 \sigma^2)S_t \, dt + \sigma S_t \, dW_t(\mathbb{P}).$$

where $\mu$ is the continuously-compounded expected return and $\sigma$ is the volatiliy. This model has a closed-form solution for continuously-compounded returns: $Y_t = \log(S_t/S_{t-1}) = \mu + \sigma \varepsilon_t$, with $\varepsilon_t \sim N(0,1)$.

The model generates a conditional likelihood for the vector of continuously-compounded returns of

$$p(Y\mid\mu,\sigma^2) = \bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \bigg)^T \exp \bigg \lbrace \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{t=1}^T(Y_t - \mu)^2 \bigg \rbrace,$$

and here is my question finally :), do i have to take for $Y = (S_1,\ldots,S_T)$ the equity prices of the underlying or the log returns $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_T)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we have here is a stochastic process $\left(Y_t\right)_{t{}\geq{}0}$ consisting of independent, normally distributed random variables $Y_t{}\sim{}N\left(\mu\,,\,\sigma^2\right)$. As you indicated, these are the "rates" or logs of continuously compounded returns over non-overlapping (hence the independence) unit intervals of time. Consequently, the likelihood function of a finite sample of these, say realisations $y_1,\ldots,y_T$, gives the density associated with observing this sequence of log returns as a function of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$: it is a product of the probability density functions of the respective log returns. That is, as you stated, the likelihood function is:

$$
p(y_1,\ldots,y_T\mid\mu,\sigma^2){}={}\bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \bigg)^T \exp \bigg \lbrace \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{t=1}^T(y_t - \mu)^2 \bigg \rbrace\,,
$$

where I have simply emphasized the fact that it is the realisations of the log returns that are important (of course, these are computed from the observed values of the underlying equity).

Comment: great, thank you. so i just want to do the gibbs sampler (MCMC) with this to get a point estimator for the unknown paramter. lets assume i have 355 observations for $S_t$. So my $Y_1 = log(S_2/S_1)$ and $Y_{354} = log(S_{355}/S_{354})$ ?

Comment: @user2016445, Yes, that is the relationship you require.

Comment: ok perfect ! :) but there comes another problem along with the closed form of the log returns $Y_t$. i derived it by myself and come up with the following closed form: 
$Y_n = log\bigg(\frac{S_n}{S_{n-1}}\bigg) 
= \bigg( \mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \bigg)n + \sigma W_n - \bigg( \mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \bigg)(n-1) - \sigma W_{n-1} 
= \bigg( \mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \bigg) + \sigma(W_n - W_{n-1})$. So finally i got a $-1/2 \sigma^2$ more, i really dont get it 

\end{equation}